# Angular 2: Why do I need to use (change) instead of (input) in IE 11 (input range slider element)?

Tags: internet-explorer, angular, slider

So I have an input slider.

```
 <input
            (change)="updateSliderValue(slider.value)" type="range"
            [min]="_minValue" [max]="_maxValue" [step]="_stepValue"  #slider
            [ngModel]="_currentValue">
```

works

but

```
 <input
            (input)="updateSliderValue(slider.value)" type="range"
            [min]="_minValue" [max]="_maxValue" [step]="_stepValue"  #slider
            [ngModel]="_currentValue">
```

does not.

But this is only an issue in IE 11.

In other browsers including Edge, this is not an issue.

I haven't tested on every single version of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Edge, but just the single copies I have on my Mac and Windows laptops (some or all may be the very latest if they auto update, if not, then very recent).

Answer (score 0):

This is because how IE11 works. The `input` and `change` events behave differently in IE than other browers.

You can use `ngModelChange` instead to get consistent behavior

```
<input
        (ngModelChange)="updateSliderValue($event)" type="range"
        [min]="_minValue" [max]="_maxValue" [step]="_stepValue"  #slider
        [ngModel]="_currentValue">
```